# Is wrapping a Task with lock not very useful?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

What intent is expressed here?:

```
lock(Locker)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        foreach(var item in this.MyNonCurrentCollection)
        {
          //modify non-concurrent collection
        }
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchonizationContext())
    .ContinueWith(t => this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyNonCurrentCollection"));
}
```

Will the system `lock` (queue) until the `Task` completes or will the system lock only to start a new `Task`? The latter implies that this lock is kind if useless, right? I am just trying to discover intent from someone else's code. The ideal here is to protect `MyNonCurrentCollection` from being modified by another thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will the system lock (queue) until the Task completes

No.

> will the system lock only to start a new Task?

Yes.

> The latter implies that this lock is kind if useless, right?

It would seem so, although you can't always be sure without seeing the full context.  For example, sometimes I'll write code that needs to check if it should start a task, based on a resource that requires locking, thus locking around code that just starts the task might be appropriate.  If you're not doing anything besides starting the task though, that's probably not the case.

> The ideal here is to protect MyNonCurrentCollection from being modified by another thread.

This does nothing to prevent that.

---

Side note, modifying a collection inside of a `foreach` over that collection is a bad idea.  Some collections will be nice enough to just throw some sort of concurrent modification exception.  Less nice collections will just produce mangled results.

Comment: I quite like that you broke down the questions and answered them individually. I'll follow that example.

Comment: So would one horrible way out would be to `lock` only around the `foreach` *inside* of the `Task`?

Comment: @rasx We don't have enough information to say for sure.  That may be appropriate.  I would also look into just using one of the collections in the System.Collections.Generic.Concurrent namespace.  Really though we don't know enough about your program to know if what it would take for it to function properly.

Comment: @Servy is it possible to make an anti-pattern by using `lock` inside of `Task` because it can cause synchronous performance (although the tasks are running on non-UI threads)?

Comment: @rasx Again, I couldn't really say without knowing more about what's going on.  Yes, it may be possible to use asynchronous waiting instead, but it may or may not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The system will lock until the task is instantiated and kicked off. Task.Factory.StartNew is asynchronous. Your lock should not be acquired for very long, even if the task takes a while.

Inside the task, you should be actually locking the shared resource, not around the creation of the task. The lock will not have an effect on the safety of the resource **unless** the task completes extremely quickly and gets preemptively scheduled before the lock is exited.

This is a bug, yes.